# Hadoop schedulers vs oozie

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie

What is the difference between oozie and Hadoop schedulers (FIFO, Fair, Capacity, Delay etc) ? Which one is normally used in production environments ?

Answer (score 1):

They offer different functions.

Oozie is a job scheduler and orchestration engine. It'll execute YARN jobs within the configured queue. For example, `mapreduce.job.queuename` in MR/Java action, `tez.queue.name` in Hive Action (on Tez), or `--queue` in Spark.

The queue you use depends on the workloads you have, but Fair or Capacity work best for multi-tenant workloads.

FIFO ordering within a queue works best if you have jobs that need to run before others, although Oozie has its own definition of how to order a full job

Also: [Job and Task Scheduling In Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081844/job-and-task-scheduling-in-hadoop)